# Good way to implement tree structure in a scalable database?

Tags: database-design, tree, nosql

I'm in need of a database engine. I think it's quite close to a simple file system. I need to do the following:

- List items in "folder"
- Scale database for reliability and speed over multiple machines
- Add/remove "folders" and "objects"
- Maybe symbolic links to avoid duplicates

Each "object" would be a set of data (key:value) up to a kB in size (guessing).

I've looked into couchbase and http://www.infoq.com/articles/graph-nosql-neo4j but they don't seem to fit my needs. Couchbase doesn't support the first requirement and Neo4j seems too advanced. (why implement a feature that's never going to be used?)

I do not need any permissions or security on the data. Just redundancy and speed. There will be a lot more reads than writes.

What is the best way to implement this? Would a folder on disk be the best way? How would one get that to span across many servers with redundancy?

EDIT:
The original problem:
We have a big amount of objects with up to something like 50 tags. Guessing an average of 10 tags. 
The client will send a list of tags to the server.
The server should return a list of all objects that contains all (or almost all) tags sent by the user.

My approach so far:
 1. Get a list of all possible tags in somewhat order of appearence (most used first). Let's call this `taglist`.
 2. Sort list from client by `taglist`.
 3. Use following algorithm:

```
algorithm( startFolder ) {
 for each object in startFolder {
      stack.push (object);
 }
 for each folder in startFolder where (folder.name is in listSentByClient) {
      algorithm( folder );
 }
}
```

4. `stack` now contains all objects which contains all tags sent by client. 
 5. Return the stack to the client

When adding new objects:
 1. Sort tags by `taglist`. Call this `sortedlist`
 2. Enter or create folder where name == first tag in `sortedlist` 
 3. Remove first tag in `sortedlist`
 4. Repeat step 2 and 3 until no tags are left
 5. Create object in current location

If this approach is wrong or you know a better one - please tell.

Comment: What are the important access paterns? Access a single folder of which you now the id? Find the Leaf folder based on a chain of successiv folders starting at root? ... any other?

Comment: @JensSchauder I think I've written what you asked for now.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to do this in Couchbase 2.0 (not 1.8.x without some very interesting keying structure, which I could actually do but is not obvious), since 2.0 is integrated with Elastic Search, but it's in pre-beta. It's also possible to do this with Views and querying.

In Neo4J you can do this by making each tag and object a node and create relationships between them (a single bi-directional relationship between object and tag). It's a fairly simple query to get all the object-nodes that are 1 level deep from the tag-nodes. Although it's a bit more sophisticated, you could also query based on the number of relationships to a group of tag nodes that an object has.

Comment: How would one use elastic search?  
Could you give an example in Neo4J if that's the best option? Anything that fits my needs would do. Open source is prefered, though.